# Getting Offline DCM reporting to auto populate in G-sheets via Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace

I'm attempting to setup more than 1 Offline DCM report to auto populate in a G-Sheet across multiple tabs. The script that I've been able to locate is not seeming to work nor does it provide a space for multiple reports. (https://github.com/fredericharnois/campaign-manager-reporting-google-apps-script/blob/master/get-campaign-manager-report.js) Any help with a generic script that I can setup?

Thanks!

Comment: Please post a [mcve] in your code. - [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.